# Removing get_template_part in child theme

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, get-template-part, parent-theme

Parent Theme loads some template files in its functions.php as follows:

get_template_part ('lib/login/register.php');

I want to remove this file in child theme and include my custom php templates.

How can I remove get_template_part function from parent theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the file to your child theme,

In your child theme, create a template and name it what ever you want, e.g `content-child.php`

Now you can replace `lib/login/register.php` with your new template:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content-child', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

It should work.